# Uninstall Postgres on Yosemite and reinstall Postgres 9.3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

I tried setting up the project https://github.com/harrystech/prelaunchr . It failed because I seem to have multiple Postgres problems.

My latest problem is:

```
 The data directory was initialized by PostgreSQL version 9.3, which is not compatible with this version 9.4.0.
```

After so many different ways I would like to uninstall Postgres now and setting up Postgres 9.3

How can I do that?

Thank you,
Benjamin

**Update:**

I managed to switch back to PG 9.3. But when I try to start the server with:

```
pg_ctl -D /usr/local/var/postgres -l /usr/local/var/postgres/server.log start
```

I get:

```
LOG:  could not open temporary-files directory "pg_tblspc/.keep/PG_9.3_201306121/pgsql_tmp": Not a directory
LOG:  could not open tablespace directory "pg_tblspc/.keep/PG_9.3_201306121": Not a directory
LOG:  database system was interrupted while in recovery at 2015-02-06 01:11:40 PST
HINT:  This probably means that some data is corrupted and you will have to use the last backup for recovery.
LOG:  database system was not properly shut down; automatic recovery in progress
FATAL:  could not open directory "pg_stat": No such file or directory
LOG:  startup process (PID 13187) exited with exit code 1
LOG:  aborting startup due to startup process failure
```

Answer (score 2):

I hope this will help you:

```
mkdir -p /usr/local/var/postgres/{pg_tblspc,pg_twophase,pg_stat_tmp,pg_stat}/.keep
```

Answer (score -2):

In your development environment, I suggest you do the EASY/STANDARD thing.

Change the config/database.yml file to use SQLITE.

```
default: &default
  adapter: sqlite3
  pool: 5
  timeout: 5000

development:
  <<: *default
  database: db/development.sqlite3
```

And you will likely also need to change your Gemfile to include sqlite.  IMO, running postgres locally is an unneeded pain, unless you're developing for some of the postgres-specific features. This app doesn't, so save yourself the bother.